# Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://172.16.70.125:8080/ when using WCF client to access service on another computer

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I'm a newbie to WCF. So here's the thing : I have two systems, one running the wcf service and the other running the client.
I'm able to ping the IP of the service, and also able to see the link when I put it into my browser. (It shows me the service is up and running).
Howver, when I try to run wcftestclient from cmd, it gives me this error :

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://172.16.70.125:8080/Service If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, ...

I've been trying this all day, and its says the same thing. 
Could someone please let me know what's wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks,
Thothathri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your service exposed a metadata endpoint?  Only relevent portions of config included

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: How do I check if metadata exchange is enabled? I'm actually able to access the service from my local computer. where do i add this code? in app.config ?? I added it in app.config and it didnt work

Comment: you add this to the .config file of your service.  You have to merge this with whatever you already have in your .config file.  Basically add the IMetadataExchange endpoint to your existing <service>, add the <serviceBehaviors> section, point your <service> behaviorConfiguration attribute to the name of your service behavior

Comment: I dont have a .config file, as my service is a console application. So, where would I have to put in the IMetadataExchange endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, yes your app.config file.  If you want to post the   <system.serviceModel> section of your app.config I can help edit it.

Comment: '<services>
 <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior"> 
          
  <endpoint address="172.16.70.125:8080/Service" binding="basicHTTPBinding" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator"/>
 
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       
 </service>
        
</services>
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>'

Answer (score 1):

The WcfTestClient utility depends on the WSDL being available for the service. The WSDL is provided by the Metadata Exchange (or 'mex') endpoint. You are probably missing that endpoint. Look for something like this in your config, or add it if it is missing:

```
<service ... >
    <endpoint ...(your usual endpoint for the service)... />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have metadata exchange enabled on your service? Your service should provide a **mex** endpoint for metadata in order for WcfTestClient to work AFAIK.

MSDN: [How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx)