# Can't access service Windows 7 self-hosted WCF app on a non-domain

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-7

Trying to run a self-hosted app on my Win 7 system, with little success. The app starts up but I can't access it from WCF Test Client or by adding a reference in VS. I've read what seems like 1000 posts about similar problems, but none of the solutions seem to fit.

I did this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9090/hello user=LocalPC\UserName
```

And then this:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:9090
```

Here's the code to do the

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/hello");

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
        {
            // Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Add MEX endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
              "mex");

            // Add application endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");                

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
            // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
            // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
            // by the service.
            try
            {
                host.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                string s = excep.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to access from WCF Test Client I get:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:9090/hello If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>   WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:9090/hello
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9090/hello'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9090/hello that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9090
>   HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:9090/hello    There was an error
>   downloading 'http://localhost:9090/hello'.    Unable to connect to the
>   remote server    No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9090

When I try to add a service reference I get:

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:9090/hello'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:9090
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9090/hello'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9090/hello that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See 
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9090
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Did you try by adding MEX behavior? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056329/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156461/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-http-172-16-70-1258080-when-using-wcf-cli . Your may also possibly wanna repair your .NET package [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189436/wcf-errors-using-wcftestclient-to-test-a-simple-wcf-web-service]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are letting the ServiceHost go out of scope immediately.

The using statement is there as a convenience to do cleanup when that block of code goes out of scope, but you have nothing in place to prevent that. So in essence you are opening the connection, but then it is being disposed almost instantly... which closes the connection.

So long as you don't run into any permissions issues, this approach should work for you. That being said, this is just demo-ware. In reality you probably don't want your WCF service tied directly to your form, but rather defined at the application level.

```
public partial class WcfHost : Form
{
    private ServiceHost _svcHost;
    private Uri _svcAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/hello");

    public WcfHost()
    {
        _svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), _svcAddress);

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        InitializeComponent();

        FormClosing += WcfHost_FormClosing;
    }

    private void WcfHost_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _svcHost.Open(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            lblStatus.Text = _svcHost.State.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }            
    }

    void WcfHost_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _svcHost.Close();

        lblStatus.Text = _svcHost.State.ToString();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string name);
}

public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string SayHello(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly correct .. I took the example for a console app, and put it into my forms app. That example had to kept host open until a enter was pressed
Thanks